# How to exclude certain urls from RxJS retry

Tags: angular

I have an angular 6 app that is configured to retry http requests 3 times on failure.
I would like to exclude certain urls from that policy: /login  (for example).

Is there a way to do that?

I could not find any answers in the RxJs documentation.

Thank you for any help

Here's my code:

```
@Injectable()
export class RetryInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor( public spinnerService: NgxSpinnerService ) { }   
   
    timer: any;
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
        Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
         
            if(this.timer){
                clearTimeout(this.timer);
              }
              this.timer = setTimeout(() =>  this.spinnerService.show(), 500);           

            let handleObs: Observable<HttpEvent<any>> = next.handle(req)
            .pipe(                                        
                 retry(3),
                 finalize(() =>{
                    this.spinnerService.hide();
                    if(this.timer){
                        clearTimeout(this.timer);
                      }
                 }
                 )             
            );          

        return  handleObs;
    };
}
```

Comment: Show use some relevant code, for example where have you implemented the retry. Maybe we can add exlusions in there.

Comment: How did you retry requests? on each request or HttpIntercepter?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the replies. I have updated my original post to include my code.

Comment: Has anyone body had this problem in the past and knows how to solve it?I would really appreciate any help.  Tnanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will have to create a function where we will be creating a HTTP headers object and we will add a custom header field(Key: value pair). This header can be passed an additional parameter in our API calls. We can use the header in the interceptor and we can write logic of our own.

```
 export function retryCall() {
      let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers = headers.set('retryCall', 'true');
      return { headers: headers };
    }
```

Add this above function in your common file.

```
intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    let isretry = request.headers.get('retryCall');
    let count = 0;
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap((s) => console.log(count++)),
      retry(isretry ? this.retryCount : 0)
    );
```

In your interceptor file access the header and use the retry operator using ternatory operator.

```
this.httpService.getAPIWithError(2, retryCall()).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('data: ', data);
    });
```

Pass the retryCall Function like above in your code. This is an optional Parameter.

```
 getAPIWithError(id: number, headers?: any) {
    return this.httpClient.get(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2/${id}`,
      headers
    );
  }
```

If you need code you can check the below link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-retry-rxjs-interceptor?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fhttp-service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fretry-interceptor.interceptor.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

If you want the explanation of my code you can check my medium article.
https://mohammedfahimullah.medium.com/apply-retry-operator-for-specific-apis-478f93742492

Comment: Nice. For more rep, you should explain it instead of just a link, but I like it.

Comment: https://mohammedfahimullah.medium.com/apply-retry-operator-for-specific-apis-478f93742492

Comment: I wrote an Angular for you. I have explained it clearly. Check the above link.